# Stopping bats from spawning in vanilla minecraft--Without killing them

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Lots of people have asked questions about how to stop mobs from spawning, but the answers are almost always to /kill them all. This is not what I want. I don't know if this is possible, but using scoreboards, gamerule, whatever, I want to stop bats from spawning in the first place. This way, somebody can use mobs like bats without them dying.
I know doMobSpawning false is a gamerule I could use, but that stops ALL mobs from spawning. It's likely relevant to note that this is on a minecraft realm, and while that gamerule is on, there's a setting that makes hostile mobs not spawn on their own while passive mobs do. Sadly, bats are considered passive despite how annoying they are. xD
I know also that this likely isn't possible, I'm just seeing if anyone knows a way. Again, no /kill involved. (Unless is somehow doesn't kill pre-existing bats... using tags? hm. If there's an NBT tag for having spawned in a spawn egg, I can use that. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a tag for being spawned by a spawn egg, but you can give entities your own tags with custom spawn eggs:

```
/give @s bat_spawn_egg{EntityTag:{Tags:["dontkillmepls"]}}
```

Now you just need to kill all bats that don't have the "`dontkillmepls`" tag. Or, even better, teleport them to y=-65, where they are deleted instantly, without animation and sound.